# Make a python file an executable

Tags: python, executable

Is there a way to make an executable from a python file, but not load the python interpreter? Both `py2exe` and `pyinstaller` do this. Is there another library that doesn't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [Nuitka](https://nuitka.net/). It converts python code into C, and then compiles that into an executable. It is also faster than the regular CPython.

> Nuitka is already slightly faster than CPython, but there is work to be done to include as many C optimizations as possible. We currently get a 312% speedup in pystone, which is a good start. (source: Nuitka version 0.6.0 with Python 2.7.)

Note: this works with both python 2 and 3